# xslt - sort in xsl:apply-templates vs sort in xsl:for-each

Tags: xml, performance, xslt, sorting

What are the flexibility and performance advantages between option (a) and (b)?
Thanks in advance.

xml data:

```
<grandparent gname="gname1">
<parent pname="pname1">
<child>cname1</child>
<child>cname2</child>
<child>cname3</child>
<child>cname4</child>
</parent>
<parent pname="pname2">
<child>cname11</child>
<child>cname12</child>
<child>cname13</child>
<child>cname14</child>
</parent>
<parent pname="pname3">
<child>cname21</child>
<child>cname22</child>
<child>cname23</child>
<child>cname24</child>
</parent>
<grandparent>
```

partial xslt code:

(a)

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/grandparent/parent">
    <xsl:sort select="@pname"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

(b)

```
<xsl:templates match="/grandparent">
    <xsl:for-each select="parent">
        <xsl:sort select="@pname" order="descending"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The performance is almost certainly entirely down to what XSLT system you are using and will vary quite heavily between different implementations - it is entirely possible that what has the best performance with one engine will be different to that with another, so the only way to be sure (and because it is so trivially easy to find out) is to try it on your own choice of XSLT engine and time it.

Comment: Agree entirely. I've seen major differences between versions of XSLT processors in different versions of same framework for example (msxml in my case) as they optimise bits from version to version that invariably lead to things being faster in one version but equal or slower in another.

Answer (score 0):

Performance: as Woody says, it depends on the processor. There's no intrinsic reason to expect any difference.

Flexibility: apply-templates is always more flexible. Though there is a balance to be found; sometimes code can be clearer and more readable with some judicious use of for-each.